# Convolution of two dependent distributions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, convolution

Assume that I have two discrete random variables **X** and **Y**.

```
X = {1,3,3,5,7,7,7,9,9,9,9,9}
```

and

```
Y = {5,5,9,9,10,12,13}
```

Where their empirical CDFs are given as:

```
F_x(1) = 0.0833, F_x(3) = 0.25, F_x(5) = 0.33, F_x(7) = 0.5833 and F_x(9) = 1
```

and

```
F_y(5) = 0.2857, F_y(9) = 0.5714, F_y(10) = 0.7143, F_y(12) = 0.8571 and F_y(13) = 1
```

Assuming their joint distribution is

```
H(x,y) = F_x(x) * F_y(y)
```

which is actually the "assumption" of X and Y are independent.

How can i calculate the **Z = X + Y** and **F(z)** in MATLAB ?

Note: I gave the **H(x,y)** as a simple product function for the simplicity, but it can be anything in reality which actually models the dependency between X and Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given continuous probability density functions *F<sub>X</sub>* and *F<sub>Y</sub>*, with a joint probability density function *F*<sub>X,Y</sub>, we can compute *F*<sub>X+Y</sub> as [the integral of *F*<sub>X,Y</sub> over the line *z*=*x*+*y*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/how-to-add-two-dependent-random-variables). If the probability density functions are discrete, the integral above should be written as the derivative of the integral over the part of the plane given by *z*<=*x*+*y*.

This is fairly simple to do in MATLAB. Let's start with OP's data:

```matlab
F_x = [0.0833,0.0833,0.25,0.25,0.33,0.33,0.5833,0.5833,1]; % CDF
F_x = diff([0,F_x]); % PDF
F_y = [0,0,0,0,0.2857,0.2857,0.2857,0.2857,0.5714,0.7143,0.7143,0.8571,1]; % CDF
F_y = diff([0,F_y]); % PDF
H = F_x.' .* F_y; % example joint PDF
```

Now we sum `F_cum(z) = sum(H(x,y))` for all values `z<=x+y`, and then take the derivative `F = diff([0,F_cum])`:

```matlab
[m,n] = size(H);
F_cum = zeros(1,m+n-1);
for z = 1:numel(F_cum)
   s = 0;
   for x = 1:numel(F_x)
      y = z-x+1;
      y = max(min(y,n),1); % avoid out of bounds indexing
      s = s + sum(H(x,1:y));
   end
   F_cum(z) = s;
end
F = diff([0,F_cum]);
```

Note that we defined `y=z-x+1`, meaning `z=y+x-1`. Thus `F(1)` corresponds to `z=2`. This is the lowest possible value that can come out of the sum of the two distributions, which we defined to start at 1.

The above can be simplified by padding `H` with zeros and shifting each row by one additional element. This lines up the line *z*=*x*+*y* on a column of the matrix, allowing us to use a trivial `sum` projection:

```matlab
H = [H,zeros(m)];
for ii=2:m
   H(ii,:) = circshift(H(ii,:),ii-1);
end
F_cum = cumsum(sum(H,1));
F_cum = F_cum(1:end-1); % last element we don't need
F2 = diff([0,F_cum]);
```

But because `diff([0,cumsum(F)]) == F` (up to numerical precision), we can skip those two operations:

```matlab
F3 = sum(H,1);
F3 = F3(1:end-1); % last element we don't need
```

(`all(abs(F-F2)<1e-15)` and `all(abs(F-F3)<1e-16)`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to answer my question, but I still do not understand why the result F has 21 values ? Shouldn't it has 22 values since Z is actually between 6~22 ? Furthermore, F(6) = F(8) = 0 which shouldn't be. It seems to me that the indices are shifted, but why?

Comment: I also have one more question. If I defined H(x,y) as H(x,y) = F_x(x) + F_y(y) for example. Do I only need to change the H = F_x.' .* F_y; line? If yes, what should I change that to ?

Comment: @Levent: I've edited the answer to explain that `F(1)` contains the probability for `z=2`. I defined it this way without really thinking about convenience of indexing, but just considering the range of possible output values. It would be simple to change that code to define this differently. -- Regarding how to define `H`: In a real-world scenario you would estimate `H` directly from your pairs of correlated variables. But of you want to define H=F_x+F_y, then you should use `H = F_x.' + F_y`. The idea is to take the x-distribution as a column vector, and the y-distribution as a row vector.

Comment: Hello @Cris, thank you again. In fact, i have another question. I defined the joint distribution as the multiplication of F_x and F_y which are the CDFs of X and Y. However, in your implementation you multiply the PDFs of X and Y. Is it true that you do ? For example, I saw in one of the papers states that H = max(F_x + G_x - 1 ,0). From your point of view this equation never results higher than 0 because not any two PDF values sum would exceed +1 for the high number of samples.

Comment: @Levent: I don't know what G_x is in that equation. But the multiplication I did is correct if you want to define H(x,y)=F_1(x)*F_2(y). Note that this is not F_1(x)*F_2(x). H is 2D here. Here H is the joint probability for two independent variables with probabilities F_1 and F_2. Now you can do F_1(x)=sum_y(H(x,y)) and F_2(y)=sum_x(H(x,y)) (i.e. summing over one dimension gives you the marginal distributions).